# ExternalInterface not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am trying to use `ExternalInterface` to add a callback function like so:

```
import flash.external.*;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("makedoom", null, forceProgress);
```

I know my function forceProgress works (It has global scope) as I have used it with a simple `onRelease` and it works as expected, however when used via externalInterface nothing seems to happen.

I embedded my SWF (on an external server) with the `allowScriptAccess` paramater set to `always`.

When I type `javascript:makedoom();` into the address bar in any browser, nothing seems to happen. I get no console errors .etc

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invoke the makedoom function on the flash dom object, it is not registered in the global JS scope.

Use `document.getElementById("theIDofYourFlashObject").makedoom()` when you are sure the swf has loaded and registered the callback already.